# Using a returned instance?

Tags: c#, using

I have a hierarchy of classes that perform API requests. In the base class, I build the request object, and in some subclasses, this method is overridden.

Base class:

```
      protected virtual HttpRequestMessage BuildRequest(HttpMethod method, Uri uri, HttpContent content = null)
      {
           HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);
           if (null != content)
           {
                request.Content = content;
           }

           return request;
      }
```

Subclass:

```
      protected async override HttpRequestMessage BuildRequest(HttpMethod method, Uri uri, HttpContent content = null)
      {
           HttpRequestMessage request = await base.BuildRequest(method, uri, content);
           request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessTokenHelper.GetAccessToken());

           return request;
      }
```

And then statements in other methods that consume the BuildRequest() method:

```
      using HttpRequestMessage request = BuildRequest(HttpMethod.Post, url, content);
```

As you can see, I'm `using` the returned instance. Will this also properly dispose of the `HttpRequestMessage` instances in each of the `BuildRequest()` methods? Or is this a classic memory leak situation after tens of thousands of requests?

Comment: There is only one `HttpRequestMessage` instance here, constructed in first `BuildRequest`, so yes this single instance will be disposed. All variables reference this single instance.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast replies! I guessed as much, but I wanted to be certain before deploying this code, as we've had unpleasant things happen with `IDisposable`s not being handled correctly before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code, there's a single instance created:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);
```

These other 2 lines only get the reference to the instance created above:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = await base.BuildRequest(method, uri, content);
using HttpRequestMessage request = BuildRequest(HttpMethod.Post, url, content);
```

So by using `using HttpRequestMessage request = BuildRequest(HttpMethod.Post, url, content);` you're correctly disposing the instance created in the base `BuildRequest` method.